# cURL receives empty body response from Nginx server

Tags: http, curl, nginx

I try to fetch HTTP content with cURL, but I only get an empty body in the reply:

```
[root@www ~]# curl -v http://www.existingdomain.com/
* About to connect() to www.existingdomain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 95.211.256.257... connected
* Connected to www.existingdomain.com (95.211.256.257) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 NSS/3.12.8.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.4
> Host: www.existingdomain.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/0.8.53
< Date: Sat, 28 May 2011 15:56:23 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-0.dotdeb.1
<
* Connection #0 to host www.existingdomain.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

If I change the URL to another domain, like www.google.com, I get the content.

How can this be possible? And how to fetch content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is free to send to the client whatever he likes, including nothing. While this is not exactly nice, there's little the client can do about this. You could

- check the server logs to see if there is some problem which makes him so calm (given the server is under your control) or
- try another client to see if the server does not like to talk to curl. You can then configure curl to mimic a regular web browser, if that helps

Comment: The server isn't under my control. I tried to set more headers, and I found one which make the server to reply content! It was the "Accept-Language" one. Without that, server replied empty responses! Thank you.